# Website hosted on heroku doesn't open in mobile

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, heroku, cors

I have hosted my app on **heroku**. When I open the app on the laptop it works fine but when I open in mobile it gives me "***No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin***" error.

Tried out many things but nothing worked. Please suggest something, find the details about app below:

**Database - MongoDB**

**Backend - express/node**

**Frontend - angularjs**

If need any more info, please let me know

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a CORS error. Install cors with `npm i -S cors`. And use it in the express app like below.

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());

/* your regular routes go here */
```

Check cors [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for more details.